# Issue with re-rendering in fabric.js objects - Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fabricjs

I'm having an issue with re-rendering in fabric.js using Vue.js v2, this my component:

```
<template>
  <div id="canvas-container" style="width: 100%; height: auto; background-repeat: no-repeat">
    <div v-show="showSmallModal" id="tooltip" class="flex flex-row absolute w-[375px] rounded-lg py-4 bg-red_color z-10 border-white drop-shadow-xl">
      <div class="flex flex-col px-4">
        <font-awesome-icon
          :icon="['fas', 'xmark']"
          class="text-lg text-gray-300 cursor-pointer"
          @click.prevent="
            {
              showSmallModal = false;
              selectedRoom = null;
            }
          " />
        <div class="flex flex-1"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="w-[10px]"></div>
      <div class="flex flex-1 flex-col justify-center">
        <p class="font-normal text-sm text-gray-300">{{ selectedRoom && selectedRoom.name ? selectedRoom.name : '' }}</p>
        <p class="font-bold text-sm text-white mt-2">&#x2022; {{ selectedRoom && selectedRoom.peoples ? selectedRoom.peoples : 1 }} {{ $t('PEOPLE') }}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="flex flex-1 flex-col justify-center items-center px-4">
        <p class="font-bold text-sm text-white">{{ starting_price }} {{ $t('SAR') }}/{{ $t(period) }}</p>
        <button class="w-[135px] h-[40px] text-sm bg-white rounded-lg text-red_color font-bold mt-2" @click.prevent="onClickRoom">
          {{ $t('SELECT_THIS_SPOT') }}
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <canvas id="canvas" class="canvas"></canvas>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { fabric } from 'fabric';
import Editor from '../../helpers/fabric/core';
import CanvasEventEmitter from '../../helpers/fabric/notifier';
import { isEmpty, toNumber } from '../../helpers';

let canvas = {};

// const availableColor = 'rgba(54, 173, 26, 1)';
// const unavailableColor = 'rgba(245,114,116,1)';
const availableColorOpacity = 'rgba(54, 173, 26, 0.40)';
const unavailableColorOpacity = 'rgba(245,114,116,0.40)';

const event = new CanvasEventEmitter();
export default {
  name: 'Draw',
  provide: {
    fabric,
  },
  props: {
    jsonData: {
      type: Object,
      default: {},
    },
    rooms: {
      type: Array,
      default: [],
    },
    onRoomClick: {
      type: Function,
      default: () => {},
    },
    loadingAvailability: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      selectedRoom: null,
      showSmallModal: false,
      lan: this.$i18n.locale,
      period: 'HOUR',
      starting_price: 0,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    if (this.jsonData) {
      canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
        selection: false,
        isDrawingMode: false,
        hoverCursor: 'default',
        width: 1700,
        height: 760,
      });
      event.init(canvas);
      canvas.editor = new Editor(canvas);
      canvas.renderAll();
      this.loadJson(this.jsonData);
    }
  },
  watch: {
    jsonData: function (newVal) {
      if (newVal) {
        canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
          selection: false,
          isDrawingMode: false,
          hoverCursor: 'default',
          width: 1700,
          height: 760,
        });
        event.init(canvas);
        canvas.editor = new Editor(canvas);
        canvas.renderAll();

        this.loadJson(newVal);
      }
    },
    selectedRoom: function (newVal) {
      if (newVal) {
        const room_prices = newVal.room_prices || {};
        if (room_prices.hourly_allowances) {
          this.period = 'HOUR';
          this.starting_price = toNumber(room_prices.hourly_price) / (1 + (toNumber(room_prices.hourly_adjustment) > 0 ? toNumber(room_prices.hourly_adjustment) / 100 : 0));
          return;
        }
        if (room_prices.daily_allowances) {
          this.period = 'DAY';
          this.starting_price = toNumber(room_prices.daily_price) / (1 + (toNumber(room_prices.daily_adjustment) > 0 ? toNumber(room_prices.daily_adjustment) / 100 : 0));
          return;
        }
        if (room_prices.monthly_allowances) {
          this.period = 'MONTH';
          this.starting_price = toNumber(room_prices.monthly_price) / (1 + (toNumber(room_prices.monthly_adjustment) > 0 ? toNumber(room_prices.monthly_adjustment) / 100 : 0));
          return;
        }
        if (room_prices.yearly_allowances) {
          this.period = 'YEAR';
          this.starting_price = toNumber(room_prices.yearly_price) / (1 + (toNumber(room_prices.yearly_adjustment) > 0 ? toNumber(room_prices.yearly_adjustment) / 100 : 0));
          return;
        }
      } else {
        this.period = 'HOUR';
        this.starting_price = 0;
      }
    },
    rooms: function () {
      this.loadJson(this.jsonData);
    },
  },
  methods: {
    onClickRoom() {
      this.showSmallModal = false;
      if (this.selectedRoom && this.onRoomClick) {
        this.onRoomClick(this.selectedRoom);
        this.selectedRoom = null;
      }
    },

    openTooltip(room) {
      if (!(this.rooms || []).length) {
        this.$toast.error(this.$t('PLEASE_SELECT_THE_VAILD_DATE_BEFORE_CHOOSE_THE_ROOM'));
        return;
      }
      if (room) {
        const _room = (this.rooms || []).find(item => item.id === room.room_id);
        if (_room) {
          this.selectedRoom = _room;
          const tooltipDiv = document.getElementById('tooltip');
          const canvasRect = canvas.lowerCanvasEl.getBoundingClientRect();
          const roomRect = room.getBoundingRect();
          if (tooltipDiv) {
            tooltipDiv.style.top = canvasRect.top + roomRect.top + 'px';
            tooltipDiv.style.left = canvasRect.left + roomRect.left + 'px';
            this.showSmallModal = true;
          }
        }
      }
    },

    mouseDown(room) {
      this.openTooltip(room);
    },

    modifyObject(room) {
      // Remove selection and controls over objects:
      room.set('selectable', false);
      room.set('hasControls', false);
      room.off('mousedown');

      // Add mouse events (if is a room):
      if (!isEmpty(room.room_id)) {
        const actualRoom = (this.rooms || []).find(item => item.id === room.room_id);
        room.set('fill', actualRoom && actualRoom.available ? availableColorOpacity : unavailableColorOpacity);
        // Mouse click:
        room.on('mousedown', () => {
          this.mouseDown(room);
        });
      }
    },

    loadJson(jsonObj) {
      if (canvas) {
        canvas.loadFromJSON(jsonObj, () => {
          canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas);
          setTimeout(() => {
            // Get objects:
            const objects = canvas.getObjects();

            // Modify each object:
            objects.forEach(object => {
              this.modifyObject(object);
            });

            // Set canvas size & render:
            if (canvas.editor && canvas.editor.editorWorkspace) {
              canvas.editor.editorWorkspace.setSize(room.width, room.height);
              canvas.editor.editorWorkspace.endDragging();
            }
            canvas.renderAll();
            canvas.requestRenderAll();
          }, 100);
        });
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style></style>
```

When the component mounts I inject the json data into fabric canvas, and I do watch the jsonData object whenever it changes it injects the new data, and so far this works fine.

Inside modifyObject I change some property in the object and then I change the fill color of the object based on the availability of the room, and so far this also works fine, but...

Whenever I click anywere in the canvas view, sometimes a random objects in fabric object changes the colors randomly between `availableColorOpacity` and `unavailableColorOpacity`, this is a weird behavior I tried to add `room.off('mousedown');`, remove mousedown event completely, and still the issue happens for unknown reason. it's like the modifyObject is being called again or something whenever canvas object is clicked.

I have a watcher for `rooms` array whenever it changes in the parent component I re-render the canvas again to know which room is available and which room is not.

But the click behavior in changing the colors randomly is weird, is there any solution for it?

[image]

As you see in the gif above, the two rooms where green, when I clicked on one of them, both of them became red until the second modal was shown then it became green again, the expected behavior should be that both of them remain green until rooms array changes.

Comment: Ensure that the watched properties are being deeply observed if nested objects or arrays are being changed. Add { deep: true } to the watch property.

Comment: Fabric's loadFromJSON function is asynchronous. When you're calling the loadJson function, you're passing the callback to loadFromJSON to modify the objects. However, there's another asynchronous operation setTimeout inside this callback. Ensure that these nested asynchronous calls don't conflict.